# Trying to save open buffers to file every n seconds in emacs, why does this solution not work?

Tags: auto-save

I want to save all open buffers to the relevant files (not an autosave file) at some regular interval (between 5 and 1 minutes).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229494/4064800) seemed like it was the correct solution:

```
; In ~/.emacs file make following changes.

(require 'auto-save-buffers)
(run-with-idle-timer 5 t 'auto-save-buffers)
```

But `eval-region` on this code gives the following error message: `eval-region: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, auto-save-buffers`. I run emacs 24.4.

Is the `auto-save-buffers` functionality no longer available? Is there some other way to do what I want? Is it actually the right tool for saving to the file I have opened rather than a separate autosave file?

I have seen `auto-save-buffers-enhanced` in the list of available packages (ie. `M-x list-packages`) and using that instead of `auto-save-buffers` might be an option, but I'd prefer a solution that only requires things that come with emacs by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not actually sure what `auto-save-buffers` is/was; I can't see a reference to it (nor to it being removed).

However if I understand the question correctly, you could do this by ditching the `require`, and then replacing `'auto-save-buffers` with `(lambda () (save-some-buffers t))` in the timer call:

```el
(run-with-idle-timer 5 t (lambda () (save-some-buffers t)))
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `save-some-buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd> for details.

Also, while it's probably obvious from the name `run-with-idle-timer`, note that your code doesn't do something "every N seconds". It triggers whenever Emacs has been *idle* for N seconds, and requires an intervening period of *not-idle*-ness before it can trigger again. In this case I imagine you're entirely happy with that behaviour, however.

Comment: Yes, this looks really good, but there is a problem with using it on my system: I'm using the GUI version of emacs in OSX and I get the native looking osx gui popup menu giving me the choice of wether I want to save this buffer, save all buffers, view changes etc. after five seconds, is there some way to override all interactive menus and just save the file?

Comment: That's weird... that argument to `save-some-buffers` means "don't ask". I can't replicate the problem (but also not using OSX). Which version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: 24.4 (when I do M-x save-some-buffers I get the interactive cli menu in the bottom, by the way) ... this is about aquamacs but may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254414/how-to-silently-save-all-buffers-in-emacs

Comment: Well yes, you certainly will get that prompt (by default) if you call the command interactively via `M-x` or `C-x s`. You can bypass that by using a prefix argument: `C-u`. None of that is relevant to my answer, though, where we're calling the function directly in elisp with that argument pre-set. Did you actually try the code?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I did put some code in my .emacs, but I didn't do it correctly. Thanks for your solution, works perfectly now!